# Drag and drop won't move ALL selected files between Finder windows

Tags: macos, finder

Here's what I'm doing:

- open a Finder window with source directory (500+ files).
- open another Finder window with target directory.
- select all files in source directory using <kbd>⌘ - a</kbd>
- grab selected files and hover target window
- press <kbd>⌘</kbd> so files are moved instead of copied
- release mouse button

But only cca 85 files are moved. Rest is left in source directory (while still selected). The same happens when copying files.

Is this something I can change (number of files moved)? An error/bug? Some app interfering with drag & drop behavior? I'm left with using Terminal to move my files, which besides being annoying isn't really possible when file selection is not a simple <kbd>⌘ - a</kbd>.

Comment: Just a guess - it's taking more time to build the move list than you're giving it. Try hover longer before letting go.

Comment: I see the correct number by mouse cursor when hovering over target directory. In fact, the correct number of files is displayed from the "start of drag event". Hovering for a minute didn't result in moving more files.

Comment: does it always move the same files? are they a contiguous selection? Do they all have the same perms? Are they the same file type, or any other obvious difference between the ones that move & those that don't?

Comment: All files are usually JPGs from an SD card. But I've just tried a bunch of other filetypes, behavior is the same (moving within same HDD is the same).

Each "drop" moves ~85 files, i.e. I have to do the "drop" again to move the next batch. When copying, same first ~85 files are "selected to copy", i.e. I'm asked if I want to overwrite files in target dir.

Comment: hmm.. can't repro - just tested with 500 photos from drive to drive & to the same drive, Tested SSD & 2xHD, not SD card.

Comment: An 86 file limit with Finder drags is mentioned at the end of the second paragraph in [this post on AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160187/finder-and-dock-issues-in-osx-10-10-1) : `And in Finder, I am only able to drag and move/copy 86 items. I can select more but when I drag them to a new folder or other location the most that will get moved is 86.`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but I've found a fix.

First, open disk utility and run first aid on your disk.

Second, shutdown the computer fully and disconnect all USB devices.

Third, Press the power button and hold command-option-p-r until the Mac reboots again. This will reset the PRAM.

I hope this fixes your issue like it did for me!

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, in System Preferences -> Accessibility
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bulk file & folder moves/copies using the Finder are more easily accomplished at the command line in **Terminal**. A benefit is that the process executes faster.

The `mv` and `cp` commands are what you need. Use wildcard file selection on the source side of the command, and create target paths from dragging the associated Finder icons into the Terminal window. Take a look at the myriad options available at `man mv` and `man cp`.

If you don't want to use Terminal, then move by enclosing the files in a folder you drag, and then burst the files out after the transfer on the target.